# How could i accomplish some kind of global states in React, so many pages/classes can update this one Boolean state with button

Tags: reactjs

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I am currently working on a react app, and have a button on a few pages. Witch have to preform the same task. "setState and read the state of this one Boolean" and act up on.

Maybe there is a simple awnser, but i cant see the approach right now.

Thanks for helping me out,
greetings Daniel

Comment: You can use context API for it. Context can store the value of the boolean and can provide value and methods to update the value. Context is provided by react itself, so there is no need to install any additional package for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lifting state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context)